# Need excel formula to deduct $100 from total sales, breakdown the $100 in bills/coins, then breakdown the remaining balance as well

Tags: excel-formula

Using this websites help (https://exceljet.net/formula/cash-denomination-calculator) i was able to figure out how to breakdown the cash in my register into bills and dollars. The problem is, the formulas calculate imaginary numbers, not actual bills or coins that exists in my register. It will tell me I need a $50 bill, when i don't actually have one.

Please look at the attached image. I expect the formula to calculate (breakdown) how many 100,50,20,10,5,1 dollar bills & 1 dollar coins, 50 cent coins, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies i need to leave for next days $100 petty cash in the register and also how many bills/coins i need to give to accounting (as actual sales) also broken down. The formula would first need to deduct the petty cash and break that down. Then, whatever is left in the register, it would need to break down also. Breaking down the remaining sales would ensure we have a strict control of our money, and would help identify any lost bills/coins. I hope the attached picture makes it easier to understand what i'm trying to do.

FYI, I haven't used VBA Code, But i am very open to the idea.

[Snapshot of excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKQZA.jpg)

Comment: A question about how you decide petty cash denominations. Say, you collect $200 broken down as $50X2 + $20x5. You need to keep $100 as petty cash. Do you want to hold on to the smallest possible denominations - $20x5 - and give the rest to the accountant? Without a clear rule, it will not be possible to arrive at a single solution.

Comment: I didn't think about that, but its a great point. I think I wouldn't want to keep $20X5 as petty cash, as i would need to have a bunch of coins and smaller bills for change. I'm thinking, maybe a rule that states the following:                               Twenty dollar bills:   1 ($20.00)
Ten dollar bills: 1 ($10.00)
Five dollar bills: 9 ($40.00)
One dollar bills:  21 ($21.00)
Quarters:          13 ($ 3.25)
Dimes:              5 ($  .50)
Nickels:            4 ($  .20)
Pennies:            5 ($  .05)

Comment: Actually, Try to keep the smaller change first, and work your way up if you don't have the minimum for each denomination.     Twenty dollar bills: 1 ($20.00) Ten dollar bills: 1 ($10.00) Five dollar bills: 9 ($40.00) One dollar bills: 21 ($21.00) Quarters: 13 ($ 3.25) Dimes: 5 ($ .50) Nickels: 4 ($ .20) Pennies: 5 ($ .05)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, came up with this, only uses sumproduct() and the solver...

You can expand it as you wish, with perhaps the initial bills and then to work out the next position...

[image]

Comment: Thank you Mike, for your quick response. I don't think i was very clear on my initial question, evident by the minus vote on my initial question. Please see the picture that i attached on my edited question. Let me know if that makes more sense. Column F should calculate first, then column F should calculate second, and the sum of both columns should not go over column C.